# python: beautifulsoup find tag by class excluding some class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="A B">123</div>
<div class="B">456</div>
```

Gonna find the div without class A, how to exclude it?

Comment: Does ur class name contain spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `class name` contains spaces, you cannot use a `lambda` function in `find_all`. Instead, you can find all `divs` and add all the `divs` that do not contain `A` in their class name to a `list`. Here is how you do it:

```
tags = soup.find_all('div')
tags = [tag for tag in tags if 'A' not in ''.join(tag['class'])]
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="A B">123</div>
<div class="B">456</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

tags = soup.find_all('div')
tags = [tag for tag in tags if 'A' not in ''.join(tag['class'])]

print(tags)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="B">456</div>]
```

Comment: `E   KeyError: 'class'` ...